# Link two networks so machines can see each other wirelessly

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

So here is what I want to do. I live in the same apartment building as a good friend and I would like to find a way wirelessly "bridge" our networks. We both have internet access and don't want this setup to result in sharing internet, we just want to be able to access each other's server on "local" connection rather than having to go out to the internet and back in (which is extremely slow).

I'm thinking something like this could be accomplished using two routers running something like DD-WRT that bridge between our networks to expose all or specific boxes to the other network. So for example if his DCHP is setup to use 192.168.1.* and use 10.0.1.* he would be able to access say 10.0.1.201 and it would go through the wireless routers instead of out to the internet and back in.

Is this even possible? I know at work we have a VPN tunnel to our data center that all traffic goes through we we hit those boxes (all internet traffic goes right out to our local ISP) but can I do this with consumer grade/cost hardware?

Thanks for any help you may be able to give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DD-WRT will do just fine using Client Bridge on second one. Use the same net mask on both routers. Set router 1 as gateway for router 2, on router 2 enable DHCP relay.. You can actually use non DD-WRT routers, preferably two of the same that have bridge functionality, most that can work as repeaters can do the job, try most TP-Link models ( activate WDS Bridging on Wireless Settings Tab -> Survey for Router_1, again same sub net, disable DHCP on Router 2 etc.. ), WPS can save you a lot of trouble in such setup so try that first, if speed is an issue than use WEP insted of WPS or better yet Open and allow only bridge router mac addresses.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try this over the weekend, marking as accepted answer for now! Thanks!

Comment: If you need support and we can happen to be both online i can help you in chat or at least give you more detailed instructions knowing the available hardware, i have done it quite a few times.